# How to retain the state of checkedBox in a listView?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-checkbox

In my application's list view I have a checkBox in every listItem.I am using this code for it in the custom BaseAdapter -

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Context context;
 private ArrayList<QuestionItem> questionItems;
 public QuestionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<QuestionItem> questionItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.questionItems = questionItems;
 }

        @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MySQLiteHelper sqliteHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context); 
    QuestionViewHolder holder = null;

     OnCheckedChangeListener mStarCheckedChanceChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                final String id = (String) buttonView.getTag();
                Log.v(TAG, "isChecked is " + isChecked);
                Log.v(TAG,"id is " + id);

            }
        };

    if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.question_list_item, null);

            holder = new QuestionViewHolder();

            holder.qid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qid);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

            holder.star = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_star);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else{
        holder = (QuestionViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }





        holder.qid.setText(questionItems.get(position).getQid());        
        holder.title.setText(questionItems.get(position).getTitle());


        holder.star.setTag(questionItems.get(position).getQid());
        if(sqliteHelper.questionexists(questionItems.get(position).getQid())){
            holder.star.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            holder.star.setChecked(true);
            holder.star.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mStarCheckedChanceChangeListener);
        }
        else{
            holder.star.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            holder.star.setChecked(false);
            holder.star.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mStarCheckedChanceChangeListener);
        }
        //star.setChecked(false);


        return convertView;
}
```

Star CheckBox's onCheckedChangeListener works fine if manually I select and unselect it.However if I select it and scroll down the listview and then again scroll up,the state of checkBox changes from selected to unselected.

How to retain the state of a checkbox?Please point me if I am missing something very trivial or very important.

Comment: only one solution. add your adapter header and I will provide you with the solution.

Comment: @hasan83 - adapter header??

Comment: @hasan83 - added.Was that you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this following link will help you.

http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Comment: It says blog does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

in every item of your list you should hold "isChecked" value, and in your getView method you should call holder.`checkBox.setChecked(item.isChecked);` , and u must to remove the implement of `OnCheckedListener` and instead implement `OnClickListener` and "play" with your `item.isChecked` value. (you should to remove the implementation of OnCheckedListener because every time u do `holder.checkBox.setChecked(item.isChecked)` the method `onCheckChanged invoke`)